# candle stock program missing one require ment in parameter

Tags: python

i have 4 parameter in this code three requirement are met, but i can't figure out how to solve missing requirement for black candle.
here is my code:

```
def FindPattern(open,close,high,low):  

    if(open < close) :

        print("white candle\n");

    elif (open > close) :

        if (20 * (open - close) <= high - low) :

            print("doji candle\n");

    elif (open < close):

        if (20 / (open - close) >= high - low) :

            printf("back candle\n");    

    else:

        print("true doji candle\n");


FindPattern(7,10,8,6)
FindPattern(12,12,7,13)
FindPattern(20,3,555,4)  
FindPattern(100,7.9,5.45,4)
```

Comment: Why you're using open < close condition twice? It always returns white because of that

Comment: What are you trying to compare? You have three cases and an else, but your first condition and third are identical.

Comment: next time use special function to format block of code - `Ctrl+K` or put ``` in line before and after code.

Comment: i want to compare four find pattern from example to met their condition for each statement above.

Comment: sorry for code format i am new to this site and don't know how to do propery. next time i will change this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same condition `open < close` in one `if/elif/else`

```
if(open < close) :

elif (open < close):
```

but (in all languages) it will execute first condition and skip others.

So you should move code from `elif (open < close):` to `if (open < close):`

```
def find_pattern(open, close, high, low):  

    if open < close:
        print("white candle")
        if 20/(open - close) >= high - low:
            print("back candle")

    elif open > close:
        if 20 * (open - close) <= high - low:
            print("doji candle")

    else:
        print("true doji candle")
```

Or you should use two separated `if/else`

```
def find_pattern(open, close, high, low):  

    if open < close:
        print("white candle")

    elif open > close:
        if 20 * (open - close) <= high - low:
            print("doji candle")

    else:
        print("true doji candle")

    # ----------------------
    
    if open < close:
        if 20/(open - close) >= high - low:
            print("back candle")
```